# BigQuery - Load Sequence File

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to load text file to Big Query
and keep the order of the text file.

My text file doesn't contain any index param that can help me to order the file later according to this index..

So if the text file look like this -
aaa
bbb
ccc

I will load it to Big Query Table and get the order when running 
select * from table
Results:
aaa
bbb
ccc

I have text file that needs to be parsed according to the order.
This why is essential to keep the order .

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery itself does not guarantee retrieving order unless you have some column to order on! So you must have it (order column)!
The only way i can recommend is to open your file in some tool - like Excel and add another column with values reflecting needed order and than save it back to file after this load to BigQuery.
If your file is too big and you cannot open it with excel  - you should use some scripting language to do same but pro grammatically.

Comment: Open one file it's not a solution since i have tons of files and i need scaled solutions.  thanks! anyway

Comment: understood. so, you should write some code in language/script of your choice to add the order column into your files.

Comment: i know, but it's not a scaled solution. every day i'm getting millions of files . if for each file i will need to open it and add order column.. it will be complex system in order to be scaled.

Comment: I doubt you can do anything here purely in BigQuery. You must have something in your files that will be used  to identify order! I feel your pain. Hope someone else on SO will come with something for you.